# F# passing an array to attribute

Tags: f#

In C# I can do this:

```
[InlineData(new [] { "foo" })]
```

When I try to do this in F#:

```
[<InlineData([| "foo" |])>]
```

It gives me a compile error:

```
This is not a valid constant expression or custom attribute value
```

Am I doing something wrong or does F# not support arrays as attribute parameters?

**UPDATE**

The issue seems related to the signature of the attribute:

```
InlineDataAttribute(params dataValues: obj[]) : unit
```

The goal is to pass the string array as a single element in params array.

Comment: I tested it with custom attribute class that takes both array and params as parameter - both seem to be working in F# (latest version).

Comment: I guess its related to Attribute signature then. Its constructor in C# has the following signature: `InlineDataAttribute(params object[] data)`. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: I think you are going to run into problems with this, I don't think F# supports array-of-array constants when emitting the metadata to initialize the attribute.

Comment: Did you try `[<InlineData([| [| "foo" |] |])>]`?

Comment: `[<InlineData([| [| "foo" |] |])>]` sadly doesn't work either, while it does work in C#. The difference probably boils down to F# handling its array literals differently to C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might have already figured that part out, but if you do `[<InlineData([| "foo" :> obj |])>]`, the compiler will stop complaining and accept the array you're passing in as the params array.  It's not what you ask for in the edit (an array as a single item in the params array), but at least you have a way of passing a params array to an attribute.

I'm not sure if it's fair to say F# is in the wrong here - having arrays as attribute arguments is only possible if you mark them as not CLS-compliant. Some details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7951143/cls-compliant-attributes-and-array-parameters).

What you could try is to pass your array as the params array to the attribute, and have your test function accept a params array (by annotating the argument with `[<ParamArray>]`).